# HTMLAgilityPack and System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack, nullreferenceexception

Hello this is my first time posting but long time user.  I searched for quite a while but couldn't find anything here that would help.

I am trying to scrape information from my works time keeping system.  They Use Work Force Optimization.  The site is terrible and im trying to make life easier for my employees.

```
var web = new HtmlWeb();
        web.PreRequest = delegate (HttpWebRequest webRequest)
        {
            webRequest.Timeout = 1200000;
            return true;
        };
        NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("MyUserName", "MyPassword");
        var proxy = new WebProxy() { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
        var doc = web.Load("https://wfo.company.com/WFO/default/WFM/ScheduleEditor#", "GET", proxy, cred);

        string test = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"mainContentScheduleEditor\"]/div[3]/ul/li[1]/div[1]/div").InnerText;
```

The nullException happens when it runs the string test line.  Below is the html from the site I pulled from chrome.

```
<div class="agendaDayHeader">
            <a href="#" class="dateLabel" data-bind="attr: {title: Aspect.WFO.WFM.DataFormat.formatAgendaWeekdayNameShortDate(NominalDate())}, text: Aspect.WFO.WFM.DataFormat.formatAgendaWeekdayNameShortDate(NominalDate())" title="Sunday, 12/6/2015">Sunday, 12/6/2015</a>
```

I wasn't sure if I should have posted the whole 2000 lines here but this is the element that I wanted to get the inner text of it should simply return the weekday and date of that portion of the schedule.

Thanks for you help in advance I hope provided enough information.

Comment: Surely, your XPath expression is incorrect.

Comment: Why do you say that?  I got it through chrome by clicking that html block posted above and selecting copy xpath.  Did I do something wrong in the syntax?

Comment: Or maybe the page doesn't load by the time you access it.

Comment: I've had some luck pulling information off the page through other methods so I don't think that's happening.